# how to use List comprehensions to get required result

Tags: python, list

I have two list

```
A=['A','B']
B=['C','D']
```

I want to display it as

```
[['AC','BC'],['AD','BD']]
```

Any help ?

Comment: You are supposed to show some effort

Answer (score 4):

```
[[internal+external for internal in A] for external in B]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `itertools.product` then `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> from itertools import product, groupby
>>> x = ['a','b']
>>> y = ['c','d']
# Group by first char
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby([i+j for i,j in product(x,y)], key=lambda x: x[0])]
[['ac', 'ad'], ['bc', 'bd']]
# Group by last char
>>> [list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted([i+j for i,j in product(x,y)], key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])]
[['ac', 'bc'], ['ad', 'bd']]
```